# Javascript: Image becomes twice its size when painted on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I'm uploading an [image file](http://www.daycomsolutions.com/Support/BatchImage/HPIM0050w800.JPG) (size 368KB) and reading it as a 64 bit **data url**. The size of the data url is `501999` bytes. When I now paint it on a canvas and try to find the size of the data url of the canvas, I'm getting a size of `1091506` bytes.

I can expect some increase after painting it on canvas, but an image blowing to twice its size is pretty weird. If I use an image of around `230KB`, the image blows up to more than 8-9 times its original size. However, if I use an image of around `50KB`, the increase in size is only marginal.

What's the reason?

**Stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mz7npw?file=index.js)**

```js
let uploadElement = document.getElementById('upload')
uploadElement.onchange = onImageChange;

function onImageChange(){
    let inputFile = event.target.files[0];

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    
    fileReader.onload = function(event){

      let imageAsBase64 = event.target.result;
      let initialSize = imageAsBase64.length;
      console.log(initialSize);

      const tempImage = new Image();//  <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('test');
      tempImage.src = imageAsBase64;

      tempImage.onload = () => {
        const element = document.createElement('canvas');
        
        element.width = tempImage.width;
        element.height = tempImage.height;

        const ctx = element.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(tempImage, 0, 0, element.width, element.height);

        let endSize = element.toDataURL().length;
        console.log(endSize);
      }
    }

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload" name="image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the reason?

One of the reasons is: You're trying to upload a `jpg` image, but when you're trying to make a copied version by:

```
const tempImage = new Image();
```

it really makes a new image with `png` format. You can check by downloading that copied version:

```
document.body.appendChild(tempImage);
```

That's why you have different sizes.

Comment: I used a png file from [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Polarlicht_2_kmeans_16_large.png), and it still showed a large increase in size (891634KB to 1154550KB). With smaller file sizes, the difference was not that big though.

Comment: @Daud `891634` and `1154550` are not the image sizes. It's the length of base64 string. So, it should be `891634` characters and `1154550` character. Both of them have the same size: `16.9M`

Comment: Its the length of Base64 strings, that's correct, but aren't these lengths an indication of file size? I also don't understand the figure of `16.9M`. The file I downloaded from the website indicated above is of `668KB`.